# If date is older than 6 months and value is X, then output this

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, return-value

I have two columns in excel, one with a date and one with a rating 'low, medium, high'.
I'm trying to write a formula to put in a third column that checks:

1. If A2 = Low and B2 (date) is older than 12 months from today(), output `Overdue`
2. If A2 = Medium and B2 (date) is older than 6 months from today(), output `Overdue`
3. If A2 = High and B2 (date) is older than 3 months from today(), output `Overdue`

If these parameters aren't met, output "Current".

This is what I have so far but I'm well aware its not right :)
Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks,

```
=IF(AND(A2="Low",LOOKUP(DATEDIF(B2,TODAY(),"m"),{0,3,6,12},{"Current", "Current" "Current","Overdue"}),(A2="Medium",LOOKUP(DATEDIF(B2,TODAY(),"m"),{0,3,6,12},{"Current","Current","Overdue","Overdue"}),(A2="High",LOOKUP(DATEDIF(B2,TODAY(),"m"),{0,3,6,12},{"Current","Overdue","Overdue","Overdue"})
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can use the excel 365 then I’d suggest creating an excel [lambda](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) function:

```
=LAMBDA(level, date, LET(months, IFS(level="Low",12,level="Medium",6,level="High",3,TRUE,0), IF(date < EDATE(Today(), -months),"Overdue", "Current")))
```

so to break it down, this is a custom function that expects 2 parameters :

- *level* is the value/reference that has low/medium/high. this is used to determine the number of months for the threshold - 12/6/3 respectively and 0 for anything else though you could change that as needed.
- *date* is the date to check if its beyond the threshold. this is compared against today minus the number of months calculated from the level. if this is before that date then this function will return “Overdue”. otherwise “Current”.

You would create a workbook level named reference with this function as the value. [image]

Here I named it IsCurrent. Then you just use that function where you want the output. e.g. [image]

Answer (score 2):

What I would suggest is to "outsource" the settings for the overdue months.

This is a good habit, as everyone looking at the table can see those settings and propably adjust them - without going into the formula.

And it is possible to use these settings in another formula :-)

If you use Excel 365 you can make the formula more readable/understandable with the LET-Formula.

[image]

`=LET( OverdueMonthsForRating, IFNA(INDEX(configOverdue[Overdue months],MATCH([@Rating],configOverdue[Rating],0)),0), OverdueDate,IF(OverdueMonthsForRating>0, EDATE([@Date],OverdueMonthsForRating),TODAY()), IF(OverdueDate<TODAY(),"overdue","current") )`

**OverdueMonthsForRating** is using a classic INDEX/MATCH to retrieve the number of months according to the Rating. In case Rating is not found 0 is returned

**OverdueDate** calculates - using EDATE - the overdue date based on the ratings date and OverdueMonthsForRating. In case Rating is not found TODAY is returned

**Finally** this date is evaluated against TODAY and the status is returned.

Classic Excel formula w/o LET:

`=IF(EDATE([@Date],IFNA(INDEX(configOverdue[Overdue months],MATCH([@Rating],configOverdue[Rating],0)),TODAY()))<TODAY(),"overdue","current")`